# Move UITableViewCell index in TableView [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to move a UITableViewCell to the end of the array once it is selected. How do I change the index of a UITableViewCell?

```
var tableViewData = ["1", "2","3","4"]
...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
    let mySelectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    // Move the cell
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your specific example (**note that this assumes that your table view has only one section**):

```
// Remove the item from the data array
let item = data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
// Add the item again, at the end of the array
data.append(item)

// Move the corresponding row in the table view to reflect this change
tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: data.count - 1, inSection: 0))
```